# Is there a way with Apache Ant to update a jar file after it's been built?

Tags: java, ant, jar

Is there a way to update a jar file in Ant?

EDIT: For example, if I wanted to add some additional files to an already existing JAR file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure, that's totally possible.  The Ant [Jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) can do anything the [jar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html) command line can do.  You do it with the `update` flag set to true instead of false.

```
  <jar destfile="/x/y/z/file.jar"
       basedir="/a/b/c/"
       update="true"
  />
```

Where the destination jar is already in existence at that path.

EDIT: To set a path

```
  <jar destfile="/x/y/z/file.jar"
       update="true">
      <zipfileset dir="/a/b/c"/ prefix="x/y/z" />
  </jar>
```

Comment: How does the update operation work? Specifically, if I have a file set in a/b/c/* that I want to add into the jar file x/y/z/* is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible.  Remember - jar is just a specialized zip (for real).  If you look at the Ant zip task, the zip even has an update example.  So, if you imagine that "filesToAdd" in my example is /a/b/c* and the destfile is x/y/z/file.jar, you should be able to get it to work.  Don't believe me?  Copy x/y/z/file.jar somewhere and try it with a test ant script and check my work :).

Comment: To clarify. Assuming I have a file structure of x/y/z in my original jar file. I have some additional files in a/b/c that i want to add into z. Will the update simply add a/b/c to the original jar file. Or can I specify the file path that is used when adding?

Comment: To specify a path, look at the Jar task docs.  It shows you how to do that using filesets.  In general the ant task documentation is very good.

Comment: Many thanks found the zipfileset as you updated your answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do this with the [Jar Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) if you set `update` to `true`.

```
<jar update="true" jarfile="${jarfile}" >
    <!-- ... -->
</jar>
```