# Liferay SDK portlet plugin: use ant target to modify .war file after being created

Tags: ant, jar, liferay, war

In a liferay portlet,  the autogenerated build.xml (created with the SDK in eclipse, autogenerated by the wizard) always looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="my-service-portlet" basedir="." default="deploy">
    <import file="../build-common-portlet.xml" />

</project>
```

Is it advisable to add custom targets to this? I want to modify the .war file after it is created. Like this: 
[Is there a way with Apache Ant to update a jar file after it's been built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721888/is-there-a-way-with-apache-ant-to-update-a-jar-file-after-its-been-built)

My war-file is huge because it is autocreated by Liferay's service builder, and it seems to be in need of a few optimizations. I want to remove the WEB-INF/src/.java files (and those WEB-INF/classes/*.class files in the .war) that are also in the WEB-INF/lib/*.jar. They seem to be duplicated. Can I do this to save space during deployment and to simplify and speed-up the deployment process.

How would such an ant-target look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, that's totally possible:

```
<project name="MyPortlet" basedir="." default="updateWarAndDeploy">
    <import file="../build-common-portlet.xml" />

    <target name="updateWarAndDeploy">
        <antcall target="war"/>
        -- modify war file --
        <copy file="${plugin.file}" todir="${auto.deploy.dir}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the general strategy, although I'm just realizing that the WEB-INF/lib/....jar (dependency in the eclipse project) is nolonger present in the .war-file (its contents were unzipped, though). Maybe there is not any room for "optimizations" after all. But generally this topic/answer might come in handy someday in the future (to add documentation to the warfile, for example)